# Quite large (400k) mysql database design for multiple users

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm seeking advice of experienced admins.

I'm working on a website, where you solve word anagrams. If it solved it should never be displayed again.

Wordbase contains ~400k entries. What would be the most effective solution to storing such data?

One way could be:

```
+---------+------------------------+
| word_id | user1 | user2 | user...|
+---------+------------------------+
|  1      | null  |  null |  1     |
|  2      | 1     |  null |  null  |
|  ...    |       |       |        |
|  400000 | null  |  1    |  null  |
+---------+------------------------+
```

Where let's say 1 = solved.

But wouldn't it become a monster quite quickly?
(+even a simple query of extending it by a new user takes forever)

Other solution is to store every solved word_id for all users, but then, it can be 6-digits for every entry and growing massively and rapidly aswell.

Also which engine would be more effective in this example? MyISAM or    InnoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `(word_id, user_id)` table to store *solved* combinations, that way you won't store the NULLs. How many words will an average user solve? 5-20 maybe? 400k * 20 = 8M rows, thats nothing (the two column table is quite compact).

Do not even try to alter the table on each new user, that would stop working really quickly.

I suggest InnoDB for anything new unless there is a specific reason against it.

Comment: Average user'll solve ~1k combinations, so let's say 1k*1k Users = 1M. If you're saying, that for two column table this is nothing I'm going for it. I was just wondering if storing nulls in such table wouldn't be more effective (in terms of quering it from database) than storing 6-digits for every entry, but structure-wise this is a big no-no anyways.

Comment: 1M rows of two integers = ~30B * 1000000 * ~2.5(indexes and other overhead) = ~80MB, so nothing when you have few GBs of RAM. Sparse table (lots of nulls) are usually very ineffective - imagine the table having 400k * 1k - 400M nulls - even when each may take just a byte, it will be 400MB just for those, without taking any overhead into account. And having column per user means user_id becomes metadata (table definition) instead of data. And the alters would become slower with every new user etc.

Comment: Just one more question regarding all this: Would setting an index on 'user_id' give any significant boost to the queries or is it just a waste of space?

Comment: You mean in the additional table? Depends on your queries and the joins you want to do with it, but usually both columns are defined as a PK and the second column is indexed separately too - in this case I suggest making `(user_id, word_id)` the *Primary key* (as you seem to be primarily interested in words for single user, not the other way around) and then just normal index on `(word_id)` (which in InnoDB is actually equivalent to `(word_id, user_id)` in this case)